Where can I find a chart for gemara that has every mesachta and the perakim listed out?
I want to arrange for people to finish Shas for someone's yahrtzeit and I want a chart that people can sign up for individual perakim.
All of the charts that I see online are for mishnayos. Does anyone know if a chart for gemara exists?

Maybe it's easiest to just take one for mishnayos and remove most of Zeraim and Tahoros?

Most mishnayos charts are grouped by Masechta, for gemara I would like each perek to be split out.

Or you can just keep Zeraim and Tahoros in, and have people learn just mishnayos for those.

https://hadranalach.com/index.php?action=t_view&id=392#tabs

@אילפא This is what I was looking for. I can work with this or a printable format.

Here is a link that you can use to create a customized url for your siyum:
https://hadranalach.com/index.php?action=t_view&id=392#tabs
Thank you Ilpha for the link.

This chart has all the perakim:
https://dafyomi.co.il/general/info/list-of-chapters-of-the-mishnah.pdf
It is from this website:
https://dafyomi.co.il/useful-resources.htm

This has all of the perakim and if no one else has anything more organized I will use this to create the chart.
